# perform deduction for each group based on the rows value in the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4],
                  'money':[300,300,300,400,400,400,500,500,600,600,600],
                  'type':['a','b','c','a','b','c','b','c','a','b','c'],
                  'total':[30,10,20,10,10,30,40,40,10,20,30]})
df
```

I wish to find the percentage for each row in the column ['total']. Example,

```
['ID'] = 1
```

we have

```
['total'] = [30,10,20]
```

I want it to be in the form of such:

```
30+10+20 = 60

30/60 = 0.5
10/60 = 0.167
20/60  = 0.33
```

so that I will get a table as below

```
ID  money   type    total   percentage
0   1   300 a   30  0.500
1   1   300 b   10  0.167
2   1   300 c   20  0.333
3   2   400 a   10  0.200
4   2   400 b   10  0.200
5   2   400 c   30  0.600
6   3   500 b   40  0.500
7   3   500 c   40  0.500
8   4   600 a   10  0.167
9   4   600 b   20  0.333
10  4   600 c   30  0.500
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` + `transform` to find sum of totals by `ID`, then divide totals by that sum:

```
df['percentage'] = df.total / df.groupby('ID').total.transform('sum')
```

---

```
    ID  money type  total  percentage
0    1    300    a     30    0.500000
1    1    300    b     10    0.166667
2    1    300    c     20    0.333333
3    2    400    a     10    0.200000
4    2    400    b     10    0.200000
5    2    400    c     30    0.600000
6    3    500    b     40    0.500000
7    3    500    c     40    0.500000
8    4    600    a     10    0.166667
9    4    600    b     20    0.333333
10   4    600    c     30    0.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for aggregate values to `Series` with sam size like original, last add [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
df['percentage'] = df['total'].div(df.groupby('ID')['total'].transform('sum')).round(3)
print (df)
    ID  money type  total  percentage
0    1    300    a     30       0.500
1    1    300    b     10       0.167
2    1    300    c     20       0.333
3    2    400    a     10       0.200
4    2    400    b     10       0.200
5    2    400    c     30       0.600
6    3    500    b     40       0.500
7    3    500    c     40       0.500
8    4    600    a     10       0.167
9    4    600    b     20       0.333
10   4    600    c     30       0.500
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('ID')['total'].transform('sum'))
0     60
1     60
2     60
3     50
4     50
5     50
6     80
7     80
8     60
9     60
10    60
Name: total, dtype: int64
```

Alternative solution with lambda function:

```
df['percentage'] = df.groupby('ID')['total'].transform(lambda x: x.div(x.sum())).round(3)
```